# Insert using LEFT JOIN and INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, left-join, inner-join

Hey all i am trying to figure out how to go about inserting a new record using the following query:

```
SELECT user.id, user.name, user.username, user.email, 
  IF(user.opted_in = 0, 'NO', 'YES') AS optedIn  
FROM 
  user
  LEFT JOIN user_permission AS userPerm ON user.id = userPerm.user_id
ORDER BY user.id;
```

My `INSERT` query so far is this:

```
INSERT INTO user 
SELECT * 
FROM user 
  LEFT JOIN user_permission AS userPerm ON user.id = userPerm.user_id;
```

However, i  am not sure how to do `VALUE('','','','', etc etc)` when using left and inner joins.

So what i am looking to do is this:

`User` table:

```
id    | name       | username    | password                 | OptIn
--------------------------------------------------------------------
562     Bob Barker   bBarker       BBarker@priceisright.com   1
```

And also the `user_permission` table

```
user_id   | Permission_id
-------------------------
562         4
```

**UPDATE**
So like this?

```
INSERT INTO user (name, username, password, email, opted_in) VALUES ('Bbarker','Bbarker','blahblahblah','Bbarker@priceisright.com',0);
INSERT INTO user_permission (user_id, permission_id) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(),4);
```

Comment: Why are you inserting into `user` when you have just selected values from `user`?  What new row are you intending to insert?

Comment: @AaronJSpetner  when you propose an edit, please make it a complete edit so that subsequent edits are not required to fix casing, punctuation, and removal of useless text like "hey all".

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You have to be specific about the columns you are selecting. If your `user` table had four columns `id, name, username, opted_in` you must select exactly those four columns from the query. The syntax looks like:

```
INSERT INTO user (id, name, username, opted_in)
SELECT id, name, username, opted_in 
FROM user 
LEFT JOIN user_permission AS userPerm ON user.id = userPerm.user_id
```

However, there does not appear to be any reason to join against `user_permission` here, since none of the columns from that table would be inserted into `user`.  In fact, this `INSERT` seems bound to fail with primary key uniqueness violations.

MySQL does not support inserts into multiple tables at the same time. You either need to perform two `INSERT` statements in your code, using the last insert id from the first query, or create an `AFTER INSERT` trigger on the primary table.

```
INSERT INTO user (name, username, email, opted_in) VALUES ('a','b','c',0);
/* Gets the id of the new row and inserts into the other table */
INSERT INTO user_permission (user_id, permission_id) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), 4)
```

Or using a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html):

```
CREATE TRIGGER creat_perms AFTER INSERT ON `user`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO user_permission (user_id, permission_id) VALUES (NEW.id, 4)
END
```

Comment: I am in need of inserting a row in the user_permission table as well along side the user table. How would i do that?

Comment: Updated my OP to better explain what i was looking to do.

Comment: @StealthRT You can't insert new rows into 2 tables without multiple statements, or a trigger on the first table.

Comment: I updated my OP again to reflect what i am thinking you mean by your post. Let me know if its correct. Would i need to run "update" between the 2 inserts?

Comment: @StealthRT Yes, just like that - but you must execute the second immediately after the first, or the value of `LAST_INSERT_ID()` will become invalid.  The `LAST_INSERT_ID()` is connection dependent, so as long as these are executed sequentially on the same connection, you'll get the right value back. If any other inserts happen in between, you'll get the wrong value.

Answer (score 28):

you can't use `VALUES` clause when inserting data using another `SELECT` query. see [INSERT SYNTAX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html)

```
INSERT INTO user
(
 id, name, username, email, opted_in
)
(
    SELECT id, name, username, email, opted_in
    FROM user
         LEFT JOIN user_permission AS userPerm
            ON user.id = userPerm.user_id
);
```

Answer (score 3):

```sql
INSERT INTO Test([col1],[col2]) (
    SELECT 
        a.Name AS [col1],
        b.sub AS [col2] 
    FROM IdTable b 
    INNER JOIN Nametable a ON b.no = a.no
)
```