# insert in a related table mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, innodb

I have two MySQL tables (InnoDB). I have created a `users` table with "id_users" as the relationship key. Then I created a second table with a foreign key reference to "id_users" in the `users` table. How can I do a MySQL Insert into the second table?

Should I use JOIN?

Comment: `JOIN` is for `SELECT` statements only. First insert into one table, then into another

Comment: How can i do this? can you give me an example?

Comment: Example of what? Of `INSERT` query?

Comment: @u_mulder: Not necessarily! I've used JOIN in DELETE and UPDATE statements a numerous times. Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209414/mysql-update-join

Comment: This link can help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12073513/insert-using-left-join-and-inner-join

Answer (score 1):

Join is only for `SELECT` statement. What you want to do is just two simple inserts :

1. Insert your row in users
2. Get the last id from users
3. Insert your row in the second table with the foreign key equal to the last id.

In mysql, this can be :

```
INSERT INTO user (id, username) VALUES (NULL, 'john');
INSERT INTO group (id, id_users) VALUES (NULL, LAST_INSERT_ID())
```

`LAST_INSERT_ID` works for the entire database... be carefull using it.

Answer (score 0):

Merlin's answer is almost correct.

You can go with PHP's `mysql_insert_id()` function to get last insert id.

If you are a novice programmer, I will prefer you to go and get you hands dirty on `mysqli` and `pdo` as mysql related functions are `deprecated`.