# Is it possible to insert data based on data that needs to be inserted in a single statement in a SQL database?

Tags: mysql, sql

So, let's say I have a database of fruits, along with recipes based on those fruits.

| id | fruit name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | apple |
| 2 | pear |

| id | recipe | fruit_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | apple pie | 1 |
| 2 | baked apple | 1 |
| 3 | poached pear | 2 |

Is it possible, using a **single** SQL insert in MySQL, to add a new fruit (banana) *and* 1 or more associated recipes ('bananas foster', 'banana bread')?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert using LEFT JOIN and INNER JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12073513/insert-using-left-join-and-inner-join)

Comment: No, it is not possible in a single statement.  A MySQL `insert` only inserts into one table at a time.

Comment: You need to use two statements. First insert the new fruit. Then insert all the related recipes, using `LAST_INSERT_ID()` to get the ID that was assigned to the fruit.

Comment: Thanks - I had thought that two statements were necessary, but hoped there might've been some advanced query that could do it in one